# Custom listview issue with checkbox

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

I'm trying to create a listview with checkboxes. so this is the issue whenever I click a checkbox and scroll it down or up, it automatically checks other checkbox in the list that i didn't click.  i already search and read other thread here with the same issue but none of them solved my problem.

this is what I have done so far.

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_songs, null, true);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            viewHolder.tvSongName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSongName);
            viewHolder.tvSongArtist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvArtistName);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        viewHolder.tvSongName.setText(_songs.get(position).getSongname());
        viewHolder.tvSongArtist.setText(_songs.get(position).getArtistname());
        viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(R.integer.btnplusview, convertView);

        viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag(); 
                    _songs.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); 


                    if (_songs.get(getPosition).isSelected()) {
                        _songs.get(getPosition).setSelected(false);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position " + position + " " + _songs.get(position).getSongUrl(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("URL", _songs.get(position).getSongUrl() + " ");
                    } else {
                        _songs.get(getPosition).setSelected(true);

                    }


                }


            });
            convertView.setTag(R.id.tvSongName, viewHolder.tvSongName);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.tvArtistName, viewHolder.tvSongArtist);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.checkBox, viewHolder.checkBox);

        viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(position);

        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(_songs.get(position).isSelected());

        return convertView;
    }
```

what should I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you scroll, setOnCheckedChangeListener is called. So to handle that in get view you need to do the below -

```
viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(_songs.get(position).isSelected());
```

You first need to set onchecked null so that on scroll when view is getting populated and you are assigning value to checkbox views, you don't call the onCheckedListener.

And then you need to call OnCheckedChangeListener

```
viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag(); 
              //remove this line from the code. The below one
                _songs.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); 


                if (_songs.get(getPosition).isSelected()) {
                    _songs.get(getPosition).setSelected(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position " + position + " " + _songs.get(position).getSongUrl(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("URL", _songs.get(position).getSongUrl() + " ");
                } else {
                    _songs.get(getPosition).setSelected(true);

                }


            }


        });
```

Comment: i tried what you said and it didn't work :( when I scroll the listview up and down it uncheck the checkbox that i clicked.

Comment: But it is not checking any other checkbox at the moment right so that part is resolved? Now we just need to ensure that there is no issue in setting checkbox as checked

Comment: I updated the ans. In your onCheckedChange you have changed the state of checkbox twice. Remove it once. @AkiBeiBei

Comment: wow! man! it works like a charm! after i do what you said it really works :) thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you scroll `setOnCheckedChangeListener` is called

Removing `setOnCheckedChangeListener` and implement `setOnClickListener`

```
viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (viewHolder.checkbox.isChecked()) {
                         your logic id true
                    } else {
                        your logic id false
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I tried this too but it didn't work, when i scroll down all the checkbox is check :( but thanks anyway for answering.